# binary numbers: strange differences between + and |

Tags: c

I'm trying to manipulating binary numbers with c. I found a strange thing with the minimum code below. Can anyone tell me what is the difference between "+" and "|" here? Thank you!

```
char next_byte1 = 0b11111111;
char next_byte2 = 0b11110101;
short a = (next_byte1 << 8) | next_byte2;
short b = (next_byte1 << 8) + next_byte2;
printf("a vs b is %d ~ %d.\n", a, b);
```

It showed: a vs b is -11 ~ -267, which is 0b11111111 11110101 and 0b11111110 11110101. I'm very confused with this result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You should never use `char` for binary/bitwise arithmetic, because it has implementation-defined signedness and might be negative. In general, use `stdint.h` over the default C types.
- In case `char` is signed, then the value inside it ends up converted to `-1` in two's complement during the variable initialization. This happens to `next_byte1` and `next_byte2` both.
- Whenever you use a small integer type inside an expression, it is usually promoted to signed `int`. So your `-1` (0xFF) gets changed to `-1` (0xFFFFFFF) before you left shift.
- Left shifting a negative operand is *undefined behavior*, meaning that any kind of bugs may rain all over your program. This happens in this case, so no results are guaranteed.
- Apparently in your case, the undefined behavior manifested itself as you ending up with a large negative number with the binary representation `0xFFFFFF00`.
- The difference between `|` and `+` is that the latter cares about sign, so in case of `+` you end up adding negative numbers together, but in case of `|` the binary representations are simply OR:ed together.

You can fix the program in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  uint8_t next_byte1 = 0xFF;
  uint8_t next_byte2 = 0xF5;
  uint16_t a = (next_byte1 << 8) | next_byte2;
  uint16_t b = (next_byte1 << 8) + next_byte2;
  printf("a vs b is %d ~ %d.\n", a, b);
}
```

And now `|` and `+` work identically, as intended.

Answer (score 7):

The problem you are seeing is because `next_byte2` is sign-extended to a full `int` before doing the bitwise operation and thus is "corrupting" the high byte.

When doing bit manipulation it's better to use `unsigned` types (that is actually what unsigned are to be used for). Plain `char` types can be (and normally are) signed types and thus are better avoided for these uses.

Comment: Also the compiler warns about an overflow from int to char when defining next_byte1 and next_byte2. There is UB in this example.

Comment: It is worth to mention that `char` is not necessarily signed type (it is implementation defined). Probably the OPs compiler defines `char` as signed type.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński: Actually in C99 it's not undefined behavior but either there is an implementation-defined result or an implementation-defined signal is raised. This means that things like the crazy back-in-time propagation of UB that modern g++ likes so much is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers should resolve your problem. I just want to add clarity around '|' and '+' operators.

- '|' is the bitwise inclusive OR operator
- '+' is the addition operator, which translates into inclusive OR
  operator with CARRY propagation for multi-bit numbers.

They are not the same operator and one should not expect the same result in general, although for some cases they might lead to the same result like in your example.